# Mysql объединить две выборки в одну

Tags: mysql

Первый запрос у меня сортируется по моему списку

```
select * from posts where id IN (1, 2, 3) order by field(id, 2, 3, 1);
```

Вторая запрос так

```
select * from posts order by `ctr` desc limit 7
```

мне надо объединить результаты в одну выборку, в сортировке как в первом запросе + второй запрос

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM ( select *, 0 as num from posts where id IN (1, 2, 3) order by field(id, 2, 3, 1);
       UNION ALL
       select *, 1        from posts order by `ctr` desc limit 7
     ) tmp
ORDER BY num, CASE WHEN num THEN `ctr` 
                            ELSE -field(id, 2, 3, 1) DESC
              END;
```